# JS поиск по массиву

Tags: javascript, массивы

Какая-то *магия, делаю точно как в рабочем примере но не работает..

Вот массив:

```js
 let myArray = [
 {n: "product1", c: 5, p: 10000.99},
 {n: "ProDuct2", c: 5, p: 5000.99},
 {n: "product3", c: 5, p: 8000.99},
 {n: "product4", c: 5, p: 430.66},
 {n: "product5", c: 5, p: 47535.45},
 {n: "product6", c: 5, p: 1111.23},
 {n: "tproduct7", c: 5, p: 5400.78},
  ];
```

Так ищу и вывожу. Выводит пустоту

```js
  function filterByName(arr, name) {
    return arr.filter(function(item, i, arr) {
      return (item.n == name);
    });
  };

  let mespeackfrommyheart = filterByName(myArray, 'product4');
  console.log(mespeackfrommyheart);
```

Вот полный код:

```js
function searchProduct(){

  let myArray = [
    {n: "product1", c: 5, p: 10000.99},
    {n: "ProDuct2", c: 5, p: 5000.99},
    {n: "product3", c: 5, p: 8000.99},
    {n: "product4", c: 5, p: 430.66},
    {n: "product5", c: 5, p: 47535.45},
    {n: "product6", c: 5, p: 1111.23},
    {n: "tproduct7", c: 5, p: 5400.78},
  ];
  function filterByName(arr, name) {
    return arr.filter(function(item, i, arr) {
      return (item.n == name);
    });
  };
  let mespeackfrommyheart = filterByName(myArray, 'product4');
  console.log(mespeackfrommyheart);

}
```

```html
<input class="buttons" value="Search" onclick="searchProduct();" type="button">
```

А вот так, вызываю

```html
<td class="left" ><input class="buttons" value="Search" onclick="searchProduct();" type="button"></td>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не работает что?, пример корректно выводим массив элементов, в данном случае всего один элемент. А если требуется вывести всего один объект, `filter`, тут является лишним.

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg А если нужно вывести все совпадения?

Comment: я же написал "А если..."(с)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так работает. А как у Вас?

```js
let myArray = [
 {n: "product1", c: 5, p: 10000.99},
 {n: "ProDuct2", c: 5, p: 5000.99},
 {n: "product3", c: 5, p: 8000.99},
 {n: "product4", c: 5, p: 430.66},
 {n: "product5", c: 5, p: 47535.45},
 {n: "product6", c: 5, p: 1111.23},
 {n: "tproduct7", c: 5, p: 5400.78},
];
  
function filterByName(arr, name) {
  return arr.filter(function(item, i, arr) {
    return (item.n == name);
  });
};

let mespeackfrommyheart = filterByName(myArray, 'product4');
console.log(JSON.stringify(mespeackfrommyheart));
console.log(mespeackfrommyheart);
```

Comment: нет, вот что мне консоль выдаёт [{…}]

Comment: @АндрейИванов `...` - это, скорее всего, и есть Ваш объект. Сделайте - `console.log(JSON.stringify(mespeackfrommyheart));`

Comment: о, а так - да, работает. console.log(JSON.stringify(mespeackfrommyheart)); Что происходит? Почему тогда тут работает с просто console.log(mespeackfrommyheart); ?

Comment: @АндрейИванов Объясните, что "не работает". Я добавил кнопку в Ваш фрагмент в вопросе - в консоли ожидаемый вывод.

Comment: я понимаю, тут да всё отлично работает, но у меня вот что выводит, скрин прикрепил, это какая-то магия, блин. ну и я тупой, это конечн тож.

Comment: @АндрейИванов кхм, кхм ... Нажмите на треугольничек слева от Ваших `[{...}]`.

Comment: да, там развернулось и показывает нужную строку и ещё какое-то _proto_, так и должно быть?

Comment: а ещё через алерт выводит [object Object]

Comment: @АндрейИванов Да, так и должно быть. `alert` показывает стартное строковое представление объекта.

Comment: а можно, ещё вопрос на будущее, какой метод лучше использовать для поиска в массиве, find или filter?

Comment: @АндрейИванов Если Вы ищете *один* элемент (например, по уникальному признаку), то `find`. А если Вам нужна *часть массива* с элементами, удовлетворяющими какому-то условию, то `filter`.